# Many to many fields in widget form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I have problem with display many to many field in form widget.
Category is not display in template.
Title is ok (is display) but category isn't - category is empty.
What can I do to display many to many fields in my template form with multiplechoice checkboxes?
Why I cant display article categories in widget form?

**MODELS.py**

article model:

```
class Article(Created, HitCountMixin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(ArticleCategory, related_name='articles')
```

category model:

```
class ArticleCategory(Created):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=False)
```

**VIEWS:**

```
class UpdateArticleView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'news/update_article.html'
    form_class = EditArticleForm
    model = Article

    def get_success_url(self):
        pk = self.kwargs["pk"]
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        return reverse_lazy("news:article_detail", kwargs={'pk': pk, 'slug': slug})
```

**FORMS.py**

```
class AddArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

title = forms.CharField(
    label="Tytuł",
    max_length=120,
    help_text="Tytuł newsa",
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control form-control-lg pr-5 shadow p-1 mb-1 bg-white rounded"}),
    required=True,
)


category = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
)
```

And in my **HTML TEMPLATE:**

```
    <form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.media }}
        {#        {%  crispy form %}#}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">EDYTUJ NEWS</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: The field is `ModelMultipleChoiceField`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield

Comment: Your `form_class` is furthermore `EditArticleForm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `form_class` in your view is a `EditArticleForm`, so you should be careful to use the correct form.

The form field for a `ManyToManyField` is normally a [**`ModelMultipleChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield), but it is not necessary to specify the form field anyway. You can make use of the `widgets` option:

```
class EditArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(
        label='Tytuł',
        max_length=120,
        help_text='Tytuł newsa',
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg pr-5 shadow p-1 mb-1 bg-white rounded'}
        ),
        required=True,
    )


    class Meta:
        model = Article
        widgets = {
            'category': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
        }
```

you can customize the label with:

```
class EditArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(
        label='Tytuł',
        max_length=120,
        help_text='Tytuł newsa',
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg pr-5 shadow p-1 mb-1 bg-white rounded'}
        ),
        required=True,
    )


    class Meta:
        model = Article
        widgets = {
            'category': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
        }
        labels = {
            'category': 'label of category'
        }
```

Comment: Thank You. It's ok but is not the best way because i cant stylish this checkboxes now. There is possibility to make like title in EditArticleForm?

Comment: @AM0k: why not? You can still add classes to the the `CheckboxSelectMultiple`, for example `'category': forms.CheckBoxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'myclass'})`.

Comment: Ohhh... Sure..!

Comment: Can I make label for this now? Im not sure what can I make this checkboxex inline... Sorry for so many questions...

Comment: @AM0k: yes, with the `labels` option.

Comment: YES! You are the best!